# Adding typeface in textview to a specific word

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to set the title of a paragraph to italic (and bold if possible) but am getting no joy out of it. 
 This is what I have so far:

```
...sound and active.\n\n HEAD \n The skull is broad and...
```

So what I would like to do is to set "HEAD" to italic and bold.

complete code:

```
FlowTextView tv1 = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);              
    Spanned spannable1 = Html.fromHtml("<html ... </html>");
    tv1.setText(spannable1);  // using html
    tv1.setText("...sound and active.\n\n HEAD \n The skull is broad and....   
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    tv1.invalidate();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
   FlowTextView tv1 = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);              
        Spanned spannable1 = Html.fromHtml("<html ... </html>");
     tv1.setText(spannable1);  // using html
     tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml("...sound and active.\n\n <b> <i>HEAD </i></b> \n 
                                           The skull is broad and....   "));
        tv1.setTextSize(20);
        tv1.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your text in `strings.xml` with the desired attributes,
like this

```
<string name="text">This is <b><i> StackOverflow </i></b></string>
```

Call this string in your activity like this

```
tv.settext(R.string.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

Strings.xml

```
    <string name="text"> <b> Head </b> \n\n The skull is broad and </string>
```

Main.xml

```
 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/text"
       android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `android:textStyle="italic"` in your textView tag. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this..
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.ITALIC);